# How to calculate timespan between two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I calculate a timespan, resulting in hours from 2 different tables?

The table contains data like this:

```
Table A. 2016-08-01 00:43:10 UTC
Table B. 2016-08-04 00:50:10 UTC
```

I actually want to have the results at time interval of 6 hours, 12 hours, 3 days, 5 days, and so on.

Comment: You should at least provide simplify input and expected output. Otherwise I doubt it is understood what it is that you are asking for

Answer (score -1):

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2016-08-01 00:43:10 UTC');
$datetime2 = date_create('2016-08-04 5:50:5 UTC');

$difference = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);

echo $difference->format("%a days, %h hours, %i min, %s seconds");
```

**Output: 3 days, 5 hours, 6 min, 55 seconds.**

You can choose whatever format you want to show.

Comment: Did this answer your questions?

Comment: The OP is expecting a SQL only solution.